# Why is this If Elif statement always resulting in the "yes" variable

Tags: if-statement

Basically I made this code to ask a user if they want to play ball:

```
print("Do you want to play ball?")

answer = input("I will throw the ball and you will catch it! Yes or no?")


if answer == 'yes' or 'Yes': {
    print("Great, lets play!")
}
elif answer == 'No' or 'no': {
    print("owwkayyyy...")
}
```

However, when it runs, if I say no it still results with the program printing "great, lets play"

I am new to coding and I seriously do not understand why this isnt working.

Comment: use (answer.lower() == 'yes') or (answer == 'yes' or answer == 'yes')

Answer (score 0):

It is because you need fix your condition for your first if statement. It is incorrect to write:

```
if answer == 'yes' or 'Yes':
```

You need to rewrite answer like so:

```
if answer == "yes" or answer == "Yes":
```

The same thing is true for your elif statement.